# How can I move files from one folder to other in Google drive using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, multiclass-classification

I have a folder(training dataset) of 4500 png files labeled `1.png` (lego block images) and so on. I also have a CSV file that has data on which `png` belongs to which class(there are 16 classes ie 16 different types of blocks and images are taken from 400 different angles).
I have to further classify another 1600 images based on this data in the 16 classes. I am trying to implement the `VGG16` model for this purpose. Is it necessary to have 16 different folders with images belonging to that class? If so, how do I move the `png` files from my current folder which has all the images together using python? Also, is there a better way to go about this task?

Comment: Drive doesn't have a `move` method as such, but you can [copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) and then [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) the original files. Can you provide the code you have tried?

Comment: @Jescanellas Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, i have not been able to find any code to help me copy the png file from original location to new location. I was hoping i would be able to find some code here , perhaps some library and direct function to copy my file in Google Drive.

Comment: I'm afraid the only help I can provide is the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and the links I posted before, as Stackoverflow is not a code-providing service. I recommend you to take a look at the links, try to do code it and ask in case you have issues. It will be much easier to get an answer.